# animating a path on click - css timeframes or js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to create an animation of a path, like a journey/timeline. The user is shown a circle (eventually to be an image), when they click this circle the animation begins and shows a path animating/traveling to another circle with a fade in effect. I have attached an image which I think explains my idea best.

My question is - what would be the recommended way of doing this? css animation or is there a jquery library that would be helpful?

Thank you[image]

Comment: Try the [jQuery path library](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path). Check the demos page - they have a sine wave example which can be easily amended to fit your needs

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

I would take svg as base. With Inkscape (or similar) like that, you can design the path visually and include the blue circle.

Than you can inject the svg-code in your html like so (copy the svg code from the generated file):

```
<div class="svg-container">
    <svg>…</svg>
</div>
```

Finally you can use javascript to reference the circle and the path:

```
 var path = document.querySelector('.path'), //these selectors are just arbitrary
     circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
```

To get a point on the path, you can use:

```
var point = path.getPointAtLength();
```

For animation, I assume that you basically know how to do that, since this would be too much to explain here. But lets say that `p` is the progress of you animation and will be in the range [0,1]. To calculate a point at a given `p` could be done like so:

```
let pointAtT = (path, t) => {
    let l_total = path.getTotalLength();
    return path.getPointAtLength(l_total * t);
}
```

Having that, you can use the `x` and `y` coordinate to manipulate the circle. Be aware of possibly applied transformations, that is why I recommend to transform everything to global coordinate space, calculate there and transform the result back to the item's coordinate space.

Documentation on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement)

There are a some svg libraries that might help you: [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/), [snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) and [Raphaël](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/).